# Как записать страну пользователя в переменную?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Я запрашиваю страну с https://ipinfo.io, но в переменную не могу записать ее. Выводит undefined:

```
var country;
$.get("https://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
    console.log(response.country); // RU
    country = response.country;
}, "jsonp");
console.log(country); // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Изучите асинхронный код в JS и вам станет понятнее

https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch
https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval

```js
$.get("https://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
    printCountry(response);
}, "jsonp");

function printCountry(res) {
  document.body.innerHTML = `<p>${res.country} ${res.city} ${res.ip}</p>`;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: console.log оно и там выводит. а как записать в переменную страну, чтобы в коде вызвать можно было?

Comment: именно если в переменную записать и вывести то undefined

Comment: @justLive666 так тут всё выводит. Это асинхронный код. Не синхронный, который выполняется сверху вниз сразу.

Comment: @justLive666 смотрите всё в ответе дубликате. там всё написано как что делать

Comment: не получается сделать :( пробовал async и await: то ошибки, то не работает. Мне нужно записать в переменную страну пользователя, которую можно использовать вне функции, как у меня в примере.

Comment: @justLive666 я это и сделал, вывел инфу на страницу. Переменная res - это то, что пришло с сервера